# Lipschitz continuity and sup of derivative norm

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

On this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties), it is stated:

> For a differentiable Lipschitz map $f : U \rightarrow R^m$ the inequality
>   $\|Df\|_{\infty,U}\le K$ holds for the best Lipschitz constant of $f$, and
>   it turns out to be an equality if the domain $U$ is convex.

I have two questions about this statement.

Question 1: does a best Lipschitz constant necessarily exists? Shouldn't be $K$ the $\inf$ of all Lipschitz constants?

Question 2: do you know a proof of the wikipedia statement, or a reference where this is proved? 
I tried to prove it by using Taylor expansion with integral remainder (which seems to make sense with the convex assumption for equality), but it did not work...

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Question 1:**  let $K$ be the inf of all Lipschitz constants. For every $\epsilon>0$, there is $K\leq L<K+\epsilon$ with $L$ Lipschitz constant. So
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|\leq (K+\epsilon)\|x-y\|\qquad \forall x,y\in U\quad \forall \epsilon>0.
$$
Lettting $\epsilon$ tend to $0$ shows that $K$ is itself a Lipschitz constant, hence it is a min. In other terms, the set of all Lipschitz constants is of the form $[K,+\infty)$. Of course, we could have observed from the beginning that it had to be $(K,+\infty)$ or $[K,+\infty)$ since $M$ is a Lipschitz constant for every $M\geq L$ if $L$ is a Lipschitz constant.

**Question 2.1:**  fix $x\in U$ and take any $h$ in the ambiant normed space containing $U$ (I guess it is $\mathbb{R}^n$ in your case, but everything works the same in the general case). Then for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ close enough to $0$, $x+th$ belongs to $U$ and 
$$\|f(x+th)-f(x)\|\leq K\|x+th-x\|=K|t|\|h\|\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{\|f(x+th)-f(x)\|}{|t|}\leq K\|h\|.$$
Letting $t$ tend to $0$ yields
$$
\|Df_x(h)\|\leq K\|h\|\quad \forall h\quad\Rightarrow \quad \|Df_x\|\leq K \quad \forall x\in U\quad\Rightarrow\quad \|Df\|_{\infty,U}\leq K.
$$

**Question 2.2:**  now assume $U$ is convex. And set $L:=\|Df\|_{\infty,U}$. Fix $x,y\in U$ and note that the segment $[x,y]:=\{x_t=(1-t)x+ty\,;\, t\in[0,1]\}$ is contained in $U$ by assumption. We will show that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$, which will prove that $L$ is a Lipschitz constant, whence $K\leq L$ and finally $K=\|Df\|_{\infty,U}$ in this case.

Recall that we denote $x_t=(1-t)x+ty$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider 
$$
I_\epsilon:=\{t\in[0,1]\,;\,\|f(x)-f(x_s)\|\leq (L+\epsilon)\|x-x_s\|\;\forall 0\leq s\leq t\}.
$$
This is clearly a closed interval of the form $[0,t_0]$ in $[0,1]$. We will show that $t_0=1$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $x_{t_0}$ and $\|Df_{x_{t_0}}\|\leq L$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\|f(y)-f(x_{t_0})\|\leq \|Df_{x_{t_0}}(y-x_{t_0})\|+\epsilon \|y-x_{t_0}\|\leq (L+\epsilon)\|y-x_{t_0}\|\quad\forall \|y-x_{t_0}\|<\delta.
$$
It follows that 
$$
\|f(x)-f(x_s)\|\leq \|f(x)-f(x_{t_0})\|+\|f(x_{t_0})-f(x_s)\|\leq (L+\epsilon)(\|x-x_{t_0}\|+\|x_{t_0}-x_s\|)
$$
$$
=(L+\epsilon)(\|t_0(y-x)\|+\|(s-t_0)(y-x)\|)=(L+\epsilon)s\|y-x\|=(L+\epsilon)\|x-x_s\|
$$
for all $t_0\leq s\leq t_0+\frac{\delta}{\|y-x\|}$. This means that $t_0$ can not be the sup of $I_\epsilon$, unless $t_0=1$. In particular
$$
\|f(x)-f(x_1)\|\leq (L+\epsilon)\|x-x_1\| \quad \mbox{i.e.}\quad \|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq (L+\epsilon)\|x-y\| .
$$
It only remains to let $\epsilon$ tend to $0$ to deduce that $L$ is indeed a Lipschitz constant as desired.

**Remark:** what makes the argument lengthy in 2.2 is that there is no mean value theorem for functions with range in a space of dimension greater than one. As we have seen, we still have a "mean inequality theorem", though, when the domain is convex. But 2.2 is much easier if $Df$ is assumed to be continuous. In this case, it suffices to write
$$
f(y)-f(x)=\int_0^1Df_{x_t}(y-x)dt \Rightarrow  \|f(y)-f(x)\|\leq \int_0^1\|Df_{x_t}(y-x)\|dt\leq \|Df\|_{\infty,U}\|y-x\|.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is crystal clear and very helpful!

Comment: A last quick question: if I understand correctly, the same argument with the integral would show that $\|f(y)-f(x)-D_x f(y-x)\|\leq\|D^2 f\|_{\infty,U}\|y-x\|^2/2$ when $f$ is of class $C^2$ and $U$ is convex?

Comment: (with $\|D^2_x f\|=\frac{sup\|D_x^2 f(u,v)\|}{\|u\|\|v\|}$)

Comment: @emeu If $f$ is $C^2$, just use the integral representation $g(1)-g(0)-g'(0)=\int_0^1(1-t)g''(t)dt$ with $g(t)=f(x_t)$. This gives $f(y)-f(x)-Df_x(y-x)=\int_0^1(1-t)D^2f_{x_t}(y-x,y-x)dt$.

Comment: thanks, I think I got it. The only thing that still bugs me is that in the multivariate case, we lose a factor 1/2 (in the univariate case, we have $\|f(y)-f(x)-f'(x)(y-x)\|\leq 1/2 \sup\|f''\|$ by using the mean value form of the remainder). But maybe this is normal since there is no mean value theorem in the multivariate case?

Comment: @emeu You get the same $1/2$ factor with the estimate above, comming from $\int_0^1(1-t)dt=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, my comment was stupid... Everything is clear now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @emeu You're welcome. See you around.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the set of all Lipschitz constats for $f$.

---

Take $\left(K_n\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}\in S^\Bbb N$ a sequence of Lipschitz constats for $f$ converging to $K_\infty$.

$\forall n \in \Bbb N, \forall x,y \in U, \left\|f(x)-f(y)\right\| \le K_n \left\| x-y \right\|$

$\forall x,y \in U, \forall n \in \Bbb N, \left\|f(x)-f(y)\right\| \le K_n \left\| x-y \right\|$

$\forall x,y \in U, \left\|f(x)-f(y)\right\| \le K_\infty \left\| x-y \right\|$

So $K_\infty \in S$

---

So we get that $S$ is closed so the $\inf$ is in fact a $\min$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that answers question 1. I just noticed my question 2 was not clear: the proof I am looking for is that of the wikipedia statement.